# How do I disable Facebook Instant Articles for my website's Facebook page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have enabled Facebook Instant Articles and have connected my WordPress site with my Facebook page. Is there a way to disable this connection to post articles like before completely or can this be performed for a section of articles which I want to publish normally without Instant Articles?

Comment: http://codegist.net/code/facebook-instant-articles-disable/ , http://www.chuksguide.com/2017/02/disable-facebook-instant-articles.html

Answer (score 3):

To remove instant articles you need to:

1. Remove the meta properties tag from your page.   To enable instant articles, you installed a tag like this:

   ```
   <meta property="fb:pages" content="123456789" />
   ```
2. Go to the instant articles configuration on Facebook and remove your URL.  Here is a Facebook help center page that tells you how to get to it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/publishertools

Source: http://www.chuksguide.com/2017/02/disable-facebook-instant-articles.html